# Removing "Default" Favicon

Tags: html, browser, favicon

I have a localhost instance I run on a given port, and when developing a site for another client, my previous clients favicon still shows in the tab even though the client has no favicon. How do I remove my previous client's favicon from the browser/server? It does it Safari, Chrome (OS X), and Firefox. I've tried the force refresh (Mac equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>) to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the browser's cache: Ctrl-Shift-Delete (Cmd-Shift-Delete), select what to clear, and for what period of time. Because the new website has the same host as the old one, browser may still think you're on the previous site and display your cached icon.

Or just add a favicon to the new site.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. Of course it would be the one thing I didn't try. I'll accept the answer once my time limit is up.

Answer (score 2):

You can force a browser to download new instances of similarly named files by adding a version to them in the form of a query parameter, and updating the version as needed throughout development.

```
<link rel="icon" href="localhost:4200/favicon.ico?version=2" />
```

Other than that, closing the tab, and in some cases restarting the browser works if force refreshing the cache didn't.

Answer (score 0):

These are typically stored in with the temp internet files on your server. Clearing the history, cookies, and meta-data should take care of this.